# Plasma Cyclotron Heating Textbook

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, resource-recommendations, plasma-physics

I'm thinking of doing an independent reading course on the subject of cyclotron heating of plasmas, and I've love to hear any textbook recommendations. So far I've only found [Gareth Guest's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3527409165), which seems quite good.

Comment: There's a 2005 textbook by Donald Gurnett and Amitava Bhattacharjee called "Introduction to Plasma Physics" that's a good starting point/introduction.  If you're looking for more advanced stuff, let me know and I can send along more recommendations.

Comment: I just went through an intro plasma course using Inan and Chen, so I think I've gotten the fundamentals down. What would you recommend for more advanced stuff?

Comment: Try looking at the following:  https://www.amazon.com/Principles-Plasma-Physics-Nicholas-Krall-dp-0070353468/dp/0070353468/ref=mt_hardcover or https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Plasma-Physics-Patrick-Diamond/dp/1107424569/ref=sr_1_fkmrnull_1